# 16.04 installation fails to boot

Tags: boot, grub2

I installed 16.04.1 on an old HP DL180  from a usb stick.  The installation went correctly, but would not boot.  I booted from the usb stick in rescue mode and ran grub-install and update-grub and installed a newer kernel.  I even asked the live rescue usb to reinstall the grub boot loader.  No errors reported anywhere.  When I reboot without the usb stick in, it fails to find grub and just gives a blank screen.  When booting from the usb stick as boot from first disk it still goes blank and can't find grub.

I reinstalled from 14.04.5 on a usb stick with all the same parameters and it works fine.  Then I did an upgrade to 16.04.1 and it works fine also.